# Error when use validators with errors.validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Learning Angular 11, I'm following a course but I'm stuck on the validation part when using the reactive form. In the video the person who explains use this:

```
*ngIf="formularioCreado.controls['correo'].errors.required"

*ngIf="formularioCreado.controls['correo'].errors.email"
```

And work fine, but I don't know what Angular version he uses. I write the same code he do, but always same the same error.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo" formControlName="correo">

  <div *ngIf="formularioCreado.controls['correo'].invalid && formularioCreado.controls['correo'].dirty">

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="formularioCreado.controls['correo'].errors.required">
      Campo requerido
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="formularioCreado.controls['correo'].errors.email">
      No es un correo electronico
    </div>

  </div> 
</div>
```

**Error**

```
Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `required` attribute in the `<input>` element. You have to add it to the `<input>` element so angular can check for this validator.

your code

`<input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo" formControlName="correo">`

correction

`<input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo" formControlName="correo" required>`